# Вызов кнопкой функции с аргументом

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Делаю свои первые шаги в kivy. Пытаюсь создать просто 4 кнопки, каждая просто нажимает стрелки на клавиатуре при помощи pyautogui.

Код:

```py
# Импорт всех классов
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

import pyautogui as pag


class MyApp(App):
    
    # Создание всех виджетов (объектов)
    def __init__(self):
        # Глобальные настройки
        self.title = 'Controller'
        
        super().__init__()
        self.btn_left=Button(text="Left", background_color ="c24b99")
        self.btn_down=Button(text="Down", background_color="00ffff")
        self.btn_up=Button(text="Up", background_color="12fa05")
        self.btn_right=Button(text="Right", background_color="f9393f")

    # Основной метод для построения программы
    def build(self):
        # Все объекты будем помещать в один общий слой
        box = BoxLayout()


        box.add_widget(self.btn_left)
        box.add_widget(self.btn_down)
        box.add_widget(self.btn_up)
        box.add_widget(self.btn_right)


        return box


# Запуск проекта
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы все эти кнопки управлялись одной и той же функцией, но с разным аргументом?

P.S. Работаю в Visual Studio Code, версия Python - 3.9.10, а kivy - 2.0.0.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @MaxGrt Тогда появляется ошибка Window.title("Controller") TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Заголовок окна ставится с помощью App.title ```class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Hello world'```

Comment: @MaxGrt спасибо! Первая проблема решена! Может, поможете мне и со второй? Хочу не делать отдельные функции для каждой кнопки, а просто обращаться к одной и той же функции с разными аргументами.